# Python library to output match fixtures as text

Tags: python

I want to plot hierarchy of match fixtures between various teams in python.
Which plot can i use in python?

The output should be like

```
-----A---|
         |--------A----|
-----B---|             |
                       |-----A
-----C---|             |
         |--------C----|
-----D---|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python module[GraphViz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/)

The very first examples in [the gallery](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/gallery/) are roughly equivalent to what you want (they are tress, not binary trees, that's all).

[image]

An example from my first link shows that this code

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table'
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)
```

generates

[image]

it is easy enough to rotate, to label the connecting lines, etc, etc, and there is comprehensive documentation.

Personally, I love to use GraphViz as it turns text into diagrams, so I run it over log files, etc. It is very popular, very stable (a few decades) and has great support.

Comment: Did you look into this? Did you find a (nother) solution?